# 'Listen' to OS X application file writing

Tags: macos, file-management

[Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) (for windows) is a great tool that allows the user to place any application in a sandbox. With this tool it's easy to check what files are stored on disk, as it places everything within the sandboxed directory.

I am looking for a way to check where an (OS X) application stores its file(s) (cache, etc).

Does something like this exist for OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using the command line, you can use **lsof**, which is a standard UNIX utility.

A good, quick guide to lsof can be found [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-lsof/). As to your question, use the command

`lsof -c firefox`

to list all the files open by the program *firefox*

`lsof -a -u yourlogin -c firefox`

to list all the files open by user *yourlogin* and (*-a*) program *firefox*

Note that you'll need to know the UNIX name for your application, not it's OSX name (e.g. not Firefox.app or Firefox (note the capital)

Comment: For those of you who don't know how to find the "UNIX name", it's (usually) the name of the file located in `YOURAPP.app/Contents/MacOS`. Just placing it here for future reference :)